# Updating Formik State whilst using Headless UI "Listbox" (which manages its own state, internally)

Tags: reactjs, formik, headless-ui

I'm struggling to get a Headless UI `Listbox` implementation working successfully with `Formik`.  After reading all the docs and scouring StackOverflow, I'm yet to find an answer.

I can get the `Listbox` to function perfectly well on its own, and `Formik` is working with other, less complex (but still custom) components.  That said, I can't get them working in unison.  Whenever I change the selection in the `Select` component, I can successfully update the `Headless UI` state (in as much as it updates to the correct value) and the `Formik` state, but for some reason the `active` and `selected` properties (within `Headless UI`) aren't working correctly (always `false`).

I assume what I need to do is to make use of the `onChange` handler so that it updates **both** the `Headless UI` state (to keep the `active` and `selected` properties updated) and the `Formik` value, but this doesn't seem to work as expected.

Does anyone have any suggestions?  Please see a minimal representation of the code below:

```js
export function TestForm() {
  return (
    <Formik
      initialValues={{ testing: {} }}
      onSubmit={ alert("Submitted"); }
    >
    <Form>
      <Select
        name="testing"
        items={[
          { id: 1, name: "Test 1" },
          { id: 2, name: "Test 2" },
          { id: 3, name: "Test 3" },
        ]}
      />
    </Form>
  )
}

export function Select(props) {
  // Get field properties
  const [field, meta, helpers] = useField(props);

  // Set initial value for `Select`
  const [selectedItem, setSelectedItem] = useState(null);

  // On change, update `Headless UI` and `Formik` values
  const handleChange = (newValue) => {
    setSelectedItem(newValue); // Update the Headless UI state
    helpers.setValue(newValue); // This seems to "break" the Headless UI state
  };

  // Return `Select` structure
  return (
    <Listbox
      value={selectedItem}
      name={props.name}
      onChange={handleChange}
      // onBlur={field.onBlur} ...Commented out for now as trying to figure out issue with `onChange`
    >
      <Listbox.Label>Test Label:</Listbox.Label>
      <Listbox.Button>
        {selectedItem ? selectedItem.name : "-- Select --"}
      </Listbox.Button>
      <Listbox.Options>
        {props.items.map((item) => {
          return (
            <Listbox.Option
              className={({ active }) => (active ? "active" : "")}
              key={item.id}
              value={item}
            >
              {({ selected }) => (
                <>
                  {item.name}
                  {selected ? <CheckIcon /> : null}
                </>
              )}
            </Listbox.Option>
          );
        })}
      </Listbox.Options>
    </Listbox>
  );
}
```

Comment: did you figure it out bro?

Comment: @redietyosef Not yet, I moved onto something else and plan to come back to it.  Any ideas?

Comment: nope if i don't find the solution ill just move on to react-select or something

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I managed to make it work like this:

```
import { useField } from "formik";

interface SelectProps {
  name: string;
  label: string;
  options: string[];
}

export const Select: React.FC<SelectProps> = ({
  name,
  label,
  options,
}) => {
  const [field] = useField({ name });

  return (
    <Listbox
      value={field.value}
      onChange={(value: string) => {
        field.onChange({ target: { value, name } });
      }}
    >
      ...
    </Listbox>
  );
};
```